# Wrapping a Monolith JSF/Spring application with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf

My team currently has an old JSF 1.1 / Spring2 / Weblogic Monolith Application.  As we start towards modernizing our application they want us to take our current architecture, as is, and basically shoe horn it into Spring Boot.

We aren't talking about breaking it down into micro-services at this point, but basically a lift from our current setup, taking Weblogic out of the picture, and running it in Spring Boot with Hikari Data Sources.

Can this be easily done? I haven't found a way to do it without extensive code changes and I don't mind suggesting a "Lets break it down into a micro-services in the next Product Increment" approach.

Outside of re-architecting our application (as we plan in the future) or doing quite a lot of code change, are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use **JavaEE** for **Weblogic**, you can migrate your application to the **Spring Boot** easy enough. The main thing is the correct import of configuration, components, resources and properties. See: [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration).

If you used in your legacy project **JPA** or even **JDBC** to rewrite backend to **Spring Data** is not very difficult.

From my point of view the main difficulty is the **JSF** version you are using. I would refuse it, because: 1) it is not fully compatible with **Spring boot** and 2) it is already out of date today. It takes a lot of effort to put it into the **Spring Boot** and still it will not work completely. If there is no time and resources to change this view technology to another, you will have to finish it to **Spring Boot**.

I don't see other real alternatives

Comment: Yes, the JSF version is horribly out of date and has been brought to the attention of multiple people.  Unfortunately, we won't be moving into a new JSF version as we'll be re-writing our front end with Angular in the next 6-12 months.

Comment: Overall it's rational. 
But the choice of front between **Angular** and **React** is a subjective choice.